# Javascript : call() ,apply() instead of bind() method

Tags: javascript

Can we call() or apply() method instead of bind() for event handlers.

I know we can usenbind() to pass in the context when using the event handler.

```
var user = {

    data : [{name:"first person wood" , age : 45},{name :"Edwards" , age:34}],
    click : function(event){
        var randomNumber = ((Math.random() * 2 | 0) + 1) -1;
        $('input').val(this.data[randomNumber].name + " ," 
            + this.data[randomNumber].age);
    }
 };

  $('button').click(user.click.bind(user));
```

In the above example we are using bind to pass the user context when the button is clicked. can we use the call() or the apply() to do the same ?
If yes, how would we achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we use the call() or the apply() to do the same ?

You can do something *similar*, but you still have to create a function (which is what `bind` does):

```
$('button').click(function() {
    return user.click.apply(user, arguments);
});
```

*(For clarity: The `arguments` above is the JavaScript `arguments` pseudo-variable, which is available inside functions and is a pseudo-array of the arguments for that call to the function. Using `apply` like this then calls the function with those arguments.)*

The disadvantage to this compared with `bind` is that the function above maintains a reference to the context in which it's created (it's a [closure](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) over that context), which in turn references all of the variables in that context (whether or not the function uses them). So in theory, if you have some variable pointing at something large and temporary that's in that context, creating a function keeps that large and temporary thing lying around when it might otherwise have been eligible for garbage collection (because, again, the function references the context, which references the large temporary thing). Engines are allowed to optimize this provided any side-effects are unobservable, and so some may and others may not. Using `bind` means that issue doesn't come up. And it's simpler.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You have to pass a function to `click`.

`bind` **creates a new function** (which calls another function with a specific context when it is called).

`apply` and `call` a function (with a specific context) *immediately*.